# batch file: how do I execute cmd commands without closing the command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk\bin\setupvars.bat

cd C:\Users\andre\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_2017\intel64\Debug

interactive_face_detection_demo.exe .....
```

I want execute this 3 commands but when it execute the first command the CMD closes and does not execute the remaining commands.

I already try de `pause` command  but didn't work.

Comment: maybe there is an exit in `setupvars.bat`? can you post the content of that as well?

Comment: @double-beep  `call` fuction solved the problem. Thanks all

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the `setupvars.bat` contains `exit /B 0`

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in first comment :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: However, this is _not_ the problem. If `setupvars.bat` file is executed without `call` command, the result is the same even if it does _not_ contain an exit command...

Comment: @Aacini depends whether we are referring to `exit` or `exit /b`. If we have `test.cmd` with `call test2.cmd & echo World` and inside `call2.cmd` we have `echo Hello & exit1` it will exit the cmd window before it `echo`s world from `test.cmd`. Call however does help if we have `exit /b` hence I asked op to check if there were any `exit` statements in `setuvars.bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `call` solves your problem. If the file has somewhere an `exit /b` command, the cmd window will close. `call` prevents this from happening:

```bat
call C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk\bin\setupvars.bat
```

However, if the `setupvars.bat` file contains an `exit` command, use `start C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk\bin\setupvars.bat`, optionally with the `/b` flag.